# Is there a tool allowing me to store some encrypted data in an image file?

Tags: encryption, steganography, image

I've seen - http://stegosploit.info/ - it's adding certain data.

I'm not that sophisticated, I just want to have in an image file:

- file header
- encrypted data
- the image does not have to be real (could be the visual representation of the encrypted data)

Is there a file format that would allow such thing? *(I understand some file formats might be difficult to work with)*.

Is there a website allowing me to submit the base image and encrypted data?

---

The goal here is to distribute encrypted data across a large number of image files on image hosting websites. *(first checking if the sites use lossless compression)*.

Comment: You can hide information in pretty much any image format that uses lossless compression and where the website doesn't transform/convert the image. You can still do it if it does... but then you need something that has enough redundancy to survive processing. But as others... I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. The whole point of stego is to hide data within real data, not just encrypt data and convert them to an image... that's super easy anyway. Use a PNG and each Pixel gives you at least 3 bytes of storage space.... but it won't look like a non-suspicious image of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any website that would allow you to do that, purely for security reasons. The point of steganography (what you're trying to do here) is to obscure the fact that there's content embedded inside other content at all.

Also, when you upload unencrypted content to a website, you are no longer the only person who has it. That makes it less secure, and as a result, you should always encrypt locally.

I recommend steghide for what you are asking.

Comment: Yep, encrypting locally. Then embedded into an image. I'm not an expert on file formats. `steghide` will try, then losless upload, etc, etc... Protecting my human rights - right to public trial. Family Law is "in private" and I'm involved in total bullshit legal fiction secret courts thought police... Thinking of dead man switch on Ethereum and IPFS too: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/is-it-possible-to-derive-public-key-from-eth-address (thank you universe)